# How to tell a docker container that is deployed to a random machine in a cluster to use DNS on its own host?

Tags: docker, service-discovery

Consider the following configuration:

```
// Create a swarm cluster
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --swarm --swarm-master node1
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --swarm node2

// Setup shell environment to talk to the swarm cluster
eval $(docker-machine env --swarm node1)

// Run a DNS server on each swarm machine
docker run -d -p "172.17.0.1:53:53" --env "constraint:node==node1" my-dns-server-image
docker run -d -p "172.17.0.1:53:53" --env "constraint:node==node2" my-dns-server-image

// Run a custom service, deployed to a random node in the swarm
docker run -d my-custom-service
```

How do I tell my custom service to use the DNS server that is running on its own host?

I know about the `--dns` argument that can be passed to `docker run`, but the problem is that I don't know which host the container will be deployed to, and thus I don't know either (A) the host IP or (B) the gateway IP for the bridge network on that host at the time that `docker run` is called, thus it doesn't seem like I can take advantage of the `--dns` argument.

I'm aware that I could modify the `my-custom-service` image to execute some shell commands to get its gateway and add a line to /etc/resolv.conf at runtime, but I'm trying to do this without having to modify the `my-custom-service` image. It is completely acceptable for me to modify the `my-dns-server-image`, though.